# Accessing the browser DevTools on Cordova

Tags: cordova

When doing normal html/javascript development the DevTools help a lot. Is there a way to use them as well when developing for Cordova?

Comment: There are multiple run options (VS?), if you use PC and Chrome device emulation, does not work exactly same as mobile browsers, but you have them.

Answer (score 0):

In the "development" phase I don't know but in any case you can build your application without a key and then install the APK on a smartphone that you will then connect to your computer.

By following this tutorial : https://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-android/ you should be able to see your application in chrome://inspect and then launch the devtools.